# add a role to a user discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles

I am trying to make a command that gives a role to a member after I type power. I already have a mute command, and that one works completely fine, But if I copy that code and change the name of the command and the role it has to give, it gives the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property of 'roles' of undefined

my code is:

```
if(message.content.startsWith("power")) {
    let role =  message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => === "Role_ID");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    member.roles.add(role)
  }
```

Comment: well no member was mentioned

Comment: Which reading of "roles" is returning undefined, `message.guild` or `member.roles`? Also you have to resolve the promise of `.fetch()`, however I believe all roles are cached once the parent guild is.

Comment: `message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => === "Role_ID");` Is this actually valid syntax? What are you trying to compare to the string `"Role_ID"`, exactly?

Comment: @Elitezen while your last statement could and probably is true, `.fetch()` would still return a promise, that needs to be awaited, even when it Resolves instantly because its cached.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if(message.content.startsWith("power")) {
    let role =  message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => === "Role_ID");
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    member.addRole(role)
  }
```